# LIlypond custom global note heads

Tags: lilypond

In lilypond I would create a custom note head by doing this:

```
myGNote = {
 \once \override NoteHead  #'stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
 \once \override NoteHead #'text =
   \markup {
     \general-align #Y #CENTER {
       \epsfile #X #2 #"./g.eps"
     }
   }
 }
{ e'4 f' \myGNote g' }
```

If I had to do multiple lines it would look something like this

{ e'4 f' \myGNote g' \myGNote g4' \myGNote g8'} etc.

My question is how can I make a global note head that would apply to all g4s etc.  This global variable would be for all gs for example and then I could create another one for all c's etc.